# iTunes backup also WhatsApp chats?

Tags: ios, backup, whatsapp.app

a friend of mine has an iPhone 3GS and is swtiching to an iPhone 4S.
Now, she's tried to backup all her WhatsApp chats using the WhatsApp backup, but it gets stuck. So I'm thinking whether iTunes backup may do that too.

I know iTunes backups everything on your iPhone, so if those chats are on her iPhone it should work, isn't it?

So should I connect the iPhone to a PC/Mac and start an iTunes backup? Would that work to get the chats back when I'll restore the backup in the 'new' iPhone?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to solve the WhatsApp backup issue, maybe with the help of WhatsApp support?

Comment: I don't know, we created a new Apple ID and logged in with this one to make another backup in that iCloud, but no way, it still gets stuck in the middle of the backup and starts back.. @patrix

Comment: Is the size of the backup smaller than the free space on iCloud?

Comment: Probably not, that's why I told her to make one from iTunes to her computer @patrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When WhatsApp backup to iCloud gets stuck**

It's a 'bit late' but I recently experienced a similar problem to the one above, date June 2016.
For people like me who - for some reason - still have to change their iPhone 4 to 6s in 2017, you can bump into the problem that Whatsapp gets stuck while backing up on iCloud. It took me a while but I solved it eventually with the following steps:

- Stop Whatsapp from being stuck: Settings > iCloud > switch off
  Document Data & WhatsApp
- Delete your current Apple ID account on your iPhone 4 Create a new free Apple ID ON YOUR IPHONE 4: Settings > iTunes en Appstore > Create new free Apple ID
- Settings > iCloud > switch on Document Data & WhatsApp Go to Whatsapp > Create backup
- On iPhone 6 log off with current Apple ID (and make sure you log off
  with iCloud AND iTunes) and log in with the new ID you created on old
  iPhone 4
- On iPhone 6 install Whatsapp from Appstore and import the backup from iCloud

iPhone 4 (iOs 7) has a problem with updated iCloud (Drive) but via this bypass you can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

iTunes backup does backup WhatsApp; if you're able to complete it you can restore it to the new iPhone.

There is a guide on the support site: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201269

Answer (score 0):

iTunes should save all your data (including Whatsapp chats & images) in a backup. Besides that, if you have iCloud turned on for Whatsapp, you should also be able to make or restore a backup at any time with iCloud.

You can read more about it here: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/20888066

[image: iCloud in Whatsapp]

Comment: Yeah it should, but it gets stuck when she tries to make a Back Up of WhatsApp :/

Comment: Tried to log out and back in

Comment: Yeah! I've contacted WhatsApp support now, will try to figure out the issue and let you updated :)

Comment: Great! If you need anything else, I might be able to help you.

Comment: Yeah thank you @JelleZwiers  Will surely let you know!